# Character Limit of 50 setting Cell.Value

Tags: excel, vba, string, char, limit

I've built a form that automates part of our process for building Spreadsheets at work it all works fine except when building a string to set as a selected cells value. this is a requirement for error tracing etc.

```
ct_cell.Value = GetCommentString()

Private Function GetCommentString() As String
   GetCommentString = PlantName & " - " & Replace(Mid(ActiveWorkbook.name, 14) _
    , ".xlsm", vbNullString) & ", " & FromSheet & " - " & SAP_Automator.cmnt_input
End Function
```

What we want to happen is for the Comment section in the sheet we are automating to look like the following: PlantName - WorkbookName, TabName - Comment input from form
at the moment most are coming out around 54 - 55 chars long and vba keeps trimming the start of the string off to bring the length down to 50

we really need to keep all these values in this string so we can easily trace errors when they occur.

is there a way around this? after a bit of googling it seems that vba's char limit is 255 and a cells char limit is 32k+ so this doesn't make any sense to me that is keeps trimming back to 50

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. the variable `PlantName` was not set as a public variable so didn't exist within the context of the `GetCommentString()` function
this happened after I done a code cleanup last week and separated alot of the clutter out into separate functions

Comment: You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to flag undeclared variables.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, I'll remember that for the future. I am fairly new to using VBA inside excel. I'd much rather be working with Python, C# or Java but this is jus the nature of excel I guess.

Comment: All of those can be used to automate Excel, as can JS/TS... Still, I hear ya 